# c3p0 access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password yes)

Tags: java, mysql, database

I can't seem to connect a database using c3p0 when I use:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rdmssql", "root", "");
```

no exception is thrown. 
However, when I try to connection using the c3p0 connection pool:

```
  private ComboPooledDataSource connectionPool;

  ...other code

  /**
   * 
   * @return
   * @throws Exception 
   */
  public Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
    return getInstance().connectionPool.getConnection();
  }  

/**
   * 
   * @param driver
   * @param hostname
   * @param databaseName
   * @param username
   * @param pwd
   * @throws Exception
   * @throws PropertyVetoException 
   */
  private void setConnectionDetails(String driver, String hostname, String databaseName, String username, String pwd) throws Exception, PropertyVetoException {
    connectionPool.setDriverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    connectionPool.setJdbcUrl(driver + "://" + hostname + "/" + databaseName);
    connectionPool.setUser(username);
    connectionPool.setPassword(pwd);

    // the settings below are optional -- c3p0 can work with defaults
    // will work on this in the future
    connectionPool.setInitialPoolSize(5);
    connectionPool.setMinPoolSize(5);
    connectionPool.setAcquireIncrement(5);
    connectionPool.setMaxPoolSize(20);
    connectionPool.setMaxStatements(180);
  }
```

an java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user: 'root@127.0.0.1' (Using password: YES) is thrown. I'm not sure if I missed some configurations for my c3p0.

Comment: What are you passing to `setConnectionDetails`?

Comment: you still have access to your db with the console/SQLWorkbench/...?

Comment: I called setConnectionDetails("jdbc:mysql", "localhost:3306", "rdmssql", root, ""). But based on one of the answers maybe "" and null are 2 different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception says it ('using password': YES).
The driver manager version does not use a password (and succeeds), whereas the connection pool version DOES (and fails).
Check the argument value passed to pwd (and make it send "").

Comment: Exactly my thoughts. I'm just wondering whether it should be `""` or `null`.

Comment: The javadocs of that setter doesn't say much (http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/apidocs/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/AbstractComboPooledDataSource.html#setPassword-java.lang.String-). You could try the options ("", null) in turn and then decide.

Comment: I never thought about using null... Let me check it out. Thanks.

Comment: using null yielded the same error. It's odd how the c3p0 tool insists on using a password.

Comment: it seems that the xml file i was reading from was passing the wrong connection information.  thanks for the answer.